# Multiple custom fonts not working in CSS + HTML despite quadruple-checking proper formatting?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm new to programming and also this website. So please keep that in mind in your explanations!
I'm making a website on Neocities and I'm trying to use multiple custom Google Fonts. For some reason ONLY THE FIRST FONT, RUBIK VINYL, IS WORKING.

**The code in my CSS DOC:**

```
/*HEADING FORMATTING */
h1 {
  font-family: 'Rubik_Vinyl';
   color: #1e1c1f;
    font-size: 5em; 
    text-align: center;
}


h2 { /*this isn't working :( */
    font-family: 'Cabin_Sketch';
    text-align: center;
   color: #1e1c1f;
    font-size: 3em;
}

/*REGULAR TEXT FORMATTING */
p { /*this also isn't working :( */
    font-family: 'DM-Sans';
    text-align: center;
   color: #1e1c1f;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

**The code in the  section of my HTML DOC:**

```
   <style>
     @font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik_Vinyl';
  src: url(https://wormgodking.neocities.org/Rubik_Vinyl/RubikVinyl-Regular.ttf);
}

    @font-face {
  font-family: 'Cabin-Sketch';
  src: url(https://wormgodking.neocities.org/Cabin-Sketch/CabinSketch-Regular.ttf);
}

   @font-face {
  font-family: 'DM-Sans';
  src: url(https://wormgodking.neocities.org/DM-Sans/DMSans-Regular.ttf);
}
    </style>
```

There is nothing else in the doc that would mess with it that i know of. I'm starting bare bones and getting my fonts right first.

Please help :(

What I tried:

- googling the problem (found only formatting errors as an answer)
- quadruple checking all formatting, font names, html tags, css formatting, etc
- crying

Comment: Your file paths are not correct: These seem to work: `https://wormgodking.neocities.org/DM_Sans/DMSans-Regular.ttf`
, `https://wormgodking.neocities.org/Cabin_Sketch/CabinSketch-Regular.ttf`. The font directories are using **underscores instead of hyphens**.  In fact "quadruple checking all urls/paths" should be no1 on any webfont troubleshooting list =)

Comment: Are you using your browser's devtools inspect facility to check things like this? Also, a simple way of checking many urls is to copy the one you have in the code and paste it into your browser address bar - instantly tells you whether that url exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

```css
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Rubik Vinyl';
            src: url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/93371/RubikVinyl-Regular.woff') format('woff');
        }


        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Cabin Sketch';
            src: url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/15530/CabinSketch-Regular.woff') format('woff');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'DM Sans';
            src: url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/29932/DMSans-Regular.woff') format('woff');
        }

        /*HEADING FORMATTING */
        h1 {
            font-family: 'Rubik Vinyl';
            color: #1e1c1f;
            font-size: 5em;
            text-align: center;
        }


        h2 {
            font-family: 'Cabin Sketch';
            text-align: center;
            color: #1e1c1f;
            font-size: 3em;
        }

        /*REGULAR TEXT FORMATTING */
        p {
            font-family: 'DM Sans';
            text-align: center;
            color: #1e1c1f;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>Hellooooo</h2>
    <p>Nice its working</p>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem with your code is that your urls to the fonts are not correct.
I made this example page with the three fonts you wanted.
I used the fonts from cdnfonts.com to make the implementation easier.
Also you should spell the font names exactly like they were declared, it matters if theres an '_' or an '-'